# upgrade OpenSSH 8.2p1 => 8.5p1

Tags: 20.04, ssh, openssh

I am trying to upgrade OpenSSH version to 8.5p1 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
When running these commands I get the following

```
ssh -V 
OpenSSH_8.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

```
dpkg -s openssh-client | grep '^Version:'
Version: 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.2
```

Security metrics reports that it is still using version 1.8.2p1.
What is the correct method to update OpenSSH to 8.5p1?

Comment: That's not how security in Ubuntu works. Instead of upgrading to a newer release (which breaks things), the Ubuntu Security Team patches the current release, then pushes the patched package trough Unattended Upgrades. You might be using the wrong metric; try using specific CVEs instead, and check for patched versions at https://ubuntu.com/security/cve